# Energy imbalance during conservation of momentum associated with the collision of a molecule with the wall of a container

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I've read a couple of answers related to this topic, but none of them answer my specific question.

My question is that, when a molecule collides with the wall of a container, having $X$ component of velocity $v_x$, the momentum imparted to the wall is $2 m v_x$ due to the conservation of linear momentum. I understand how this part of the analysis makes sense, but where does the energy come from, to impart $2 m v_x$ momentum to the wall?

Answer (score 0):

The momentum **change** in a particular direction is $2mv_{\rm x}$.

So assume that the initial momentum is $mv_{\rm x}\hat x$ and after rebound the final momentum is $mv_{\rm x}(-\hat x)$ then the change in momentum is $mv_{\rm x}(-\hat x) - mv_{\rm x}\hat x = -2mv_{\rm x}\hat x$ ie a change of momentum of $2mv_{\rm x}$ in the $(-\hat x)$ direction.

Note that the speed of the molecule $v_{\rm x}$ does not change.

Answer (score 0):

> when a molecule collides with the wall of a container, having x component of velocity , the momentum imparted to the wall is 2mvx. Using the conservation of linear momentum i understand how this makes sense, but where does the energy come from, to impart 2 velocity to the wall?

Before we worry about where the energy comes from, let’s check and see how much energy is required. The energy before the collision is $\frac{1}{2}mv_x^2$. The energy after the collision is $\frac{1}{2}m(-v_x)^2=\frac{1}{2}mv_x^2$.

Notice that the energy after the collision is the same as the energy before the collision. So the difference in energy is 0. The wall supplies 0 energy.

This is a bit weird, but it shows up elsewhere. A force is a transfer of momentum. A power is a transfer of energy. They are not the same thing. An interaction can easily result in the transfer of one but not the other. Momentum and energy are separate quantities that are separately transferred and separately conserved.

Answer (score 0):

The change in linear momentum of the particle traveling along the $X$ axis towards the wall with speed $v_x$ is initially $m v_x \hat{i}_x$ and finally $- m v_x \hat{i}_x$. Since the speed of the molecule is unchanged due to the collision, there is no appreciable mechanical energy exchange due to the molecule. The change in momentum $- 2 m v_x \hat{i}_x$ of the molecule must be caused by an impulse force $F_x \hat{i}$ acted on it by the wall over the short time $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$, $F_x \Delta t \hat{i}_x  = - 2 m v_x \hat{i}_x$ so that $F_x = -\frac{2 m v_x}{\Delta t}$. An equal and opposite force is acted on the wall by the molecule. However the displacement of the molecule $s_{mol} \hat{i}_x$ and that of the wall surface $s_{wall} \hat{i}_x$ on which the reaction of the impulse force have negligible magnitudes $0 \leftarrow s_{mol}<0, 0<s_{wall} \rightarrow 0$ so that the work-done on the system (molecule $\cup$ wall surface) $|F_x s_{mol} \Delta t| + |- F_x s_{wall} \Delta t|$ vanishes.

The physical intuition is that the molecule changes the direction of it's momentum without losing energy and the therefore does undergo energy exchange with the wall surface. At the same time, a prescient question is how is the wall able to provide for the momentum exchange across a large number of such exchanges, all in the same direction (the wall should start gaining momentum in the positive $X$ direction). However, the momentum gain by the wall also vanishes due to averaging across the momentum exchange across the opposite side of the container which loses momentum at an identical rate as that at which it is gained by the one side of it.